# Discrete scheme: mass conservation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967.pdf), p. 14.

On that page, it is said that the scheme

$$
\begin{equation*}
\varepsilon\Delta x_i\Delta v_j(f_{ij}^{n+1}-f_{ij}^n)+\Delta t(\mathcal{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}-\mathcal{F}_{i-\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1})=\frac{\Delta t}{\varepsilon}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j(\rho_i^{n+1}\mathcal{M}_j-f_{ij}^{n+1})
\end{equation*}
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}:=\Delta v_j\frac{f_{ij}^{n+1}+f_{i+1,j}^{n+1}}{2}v_j.
$$

satisfies
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j f_{i,j}^n=\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j f_{i,j}^0\qquad\forall n\geq 0\tag{#}
$$
and that this is due to the assumptions on $\mathcal{M}_j$ which are given on page 11 and read
$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{M}_j >0,\quad \mathcal{M}_j=\mathcal{M}_{-j+1},\quad\forall j=1,\ldots, L,\\
&\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}\mathcal{M}_j\Delta v_j=1
\end{align*}
$$

How to deduce (#) from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sum the scheme's equation over all indices $i$ and $j$, a lot of the terms will actually vanish :
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}} \mathcal{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1} - \mathcal{F}_{i-\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}
= 0,
$$
(as I assume $\mathcal{F} = 0$ at the boundary in $i$?)

Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}} \Delta x_i \Delta v_j (\rho_i^{n+1} \mathcal{M}_j - f_{ij}^{n+1})
&= \sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}} \Delta x_i \left(\rho_i^{n+1} \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} \mathcal{M}_j \Delta v_j - \rho^{n+1}_i\right) \\
&=\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}} \Delta x_i \left(\rho_i^{n+1} - \rho^{n+1}_i\right)
= 0.
\end{align*}

All that's left of the scheme is the most left-side term :
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}} \varepsilon \Delta x_i \Delta v_j (f_{ij}^{n+1} - f_{ij}^n) = 0,
$$
hence (#) by induction.

Comment: Separating $\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}$ into $\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ and $\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}}$, the only terms that depend on $j$ are $\Delta v_j \mathcal{M}_j$ and $\Delta v_j f^{n+1}_{ij}$. Using the second assumption on $\mathcal{M}_j$, the sum of $\Delta v_j \mathcal{M}_j$ is $1$, and the sum over $j$ of $\Delta v_j f^{n+1}_{ij}$ is $\rho_i^n$ by definition.

Comment: As far as I see,
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}} \mathcal{F}_{i+\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1} - \mathcal{F}_{i-\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_j\Delta v_j v_j\sum_i (f_{i+1,j}^{n+1}-f_{i-1,j}^{n+1})=0,
$$
since the last term with respect to $i\in\mathcal{I}$ has to be seen modulo $N$, and thus all the summands cancel.

Comment: Yup pretty much, I don't know how $\mathcal{I}$ is indexed in the paper, but assuming it's something like $\mathcal{I} = (i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_N)$, that sum becomes $$\sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} \sum_{k=1}^N \mathcal{F}^{n+1}_{i_k+\frac{1}{2},j} - \mathcal{F}^{n+1}_{i_{k-1}+\frac{1}{2},j} = \sum_{j\in\mathcal{J}} \mathcal{F}^{n+1}_{i_{N+1}+\frac{1}{2},j} - \mathcal{F}^{n+1}_{i_0+\frac{1}{2},j},$$ and I assume the boundary conditions are such that $\mathcal{F}^{n+1}_{i_0,j} = \mathcal{F}^{n+1}_{i_{N+1},j}$.

Comment: In the paper, $i\in\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, so modulo $N$. This should mean, for instance $f_{-1,j}=f_{N-1,j}$.

Comment: Then yeah, the interior terms cancel each other out in the sum, and since it's periodic, the terms at each boundary do too.